# How is the oracle driver version determine with the version recommender

Tags: gradle, intershop

Since version 7.8 (I think) the version recommender determines the correct version of the different cartridge for the assembly. In the past you could modify its behaviour by setting filter version properties, for example, the oracle drivers version:

```
#gradle.properties in assembly
version.com.intershop.3rd_oracle = 12.1.0.2.1
```

Question is how is this determined now and is it possible to modify this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `build.gradle` file of your component set you can specify a file which contains the library versions via a properties provider:

```
versionRecommendation {
    provider {
        properties('intershopBase', file('intershopBase.version')) {}
        // ... (other providers here)
    }
}
```

Make sure to add this provider before the other ones so it takes precedence.

You can then specify the specific dependency in this file (`intershopBase.version` in the example above):

```
com.intershop:3rd_oracle = 12.1.0.2.1
```